# crontab no working

Tags: cron

I have crontab :

```
35 16 * * * mysqldump -h mysql2.alwaysdata.com -u user -ppass --all-databases > ../copias/fichero_`date +%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S`.sql
```

but the command working correctly without crontab.
the folder `chmod 777 -R`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should use an absolute path instead of `../copias/fichero...`.

You don't know what the current directory will be when the command is run by cron.

Answer (score 0):

In the /etc/crontab file you must specify the username as well before the command to run.

Comment: Note that in editing crontab with "crontab -e", you don't need to specify the username.

Comment: :) I know you know, just wanted to avoid confusion

Comment: paradasymfony@ssh:~/www$ crontab -l
43 16 * * * mysqldump -h mysql2.alwaysdata.com -u user -ppass --all-databases > www/fichero_`date +%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S`.sql